# How do the new Windows 8 App logos work?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8, manifest

In the Windows 8 App manifest file, I see a handful of different fields. For example:

```
Logo
Wide Logo
Small Logo
Store Logo
Badge Logo
Splash Screen
```

Each of these also have their own scaled assets, too.

So, if I want to scale my app's image (since I usually create graphics with Fireworks or Illustrator), how do I properly set all of the images for my app? I would like to support all of the scales possible by re-sizing my image to fit the scaled values...or am I supposed to go about it differently by creating an image with multiple sub-scales within it? Is there a name for that? I'm a little bit confused here...essentially, how does this all work?

Comment: I just resize the same image and it gets accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog post from Jerry Nixon about logo resizing, he use Expression Design but it should be similar with Fireworks or Illustrator: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/09/windows-81-says-forget-all-that-design.html

Comment: werid if I goto blog.jerrynixon.com it doesn't work for me either edit your answer and I will take my - away

Answer (score 0):

Check out this MSDN post

[Choosing your app images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh846296.aspx)

But I would recommend you to check out [Jerry Nixon](https://twitter.com/jerrynixon)'s this article.

[Windows 8 apps need 28 logo varietals; enter Expression Design](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/08/windows-8-apps-need-28-logo-varietals.html)